# Full path to files in res/raw folder

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-resources, android-file

I have an Android app (targeting Android R - API lvl 30) which has bulk of its logic in c++.
App reads a file in res folder and we can access it like - R.raw.dev, where dev is the config file.

My intention is to get the full path to this file and open it in C++ layer using fopen method. But I'm not able to get the full path to the file.

I have seen some suggestions of the following kind,

```
Uri resRawUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + getPackageName() + R.raw.dev);
```

But this is an Uri....not a file path.

I've heard of an alternative to the res folder, called assets, which gives more freedom than the res folder. The methods of [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager), the class used to query the assets folder, return InputStream and others, but not the file path.

Is there a way to get the absolute file path to files in res or assets folder? If its not possible in these two folders, how about external storage? Is there a way to get the absolute file path, so that I can pass this path to C++ and open it using fopen?

Comment: right click on the file , then select copy path and use it by pasting it where you want

Comment: @daksh I meant to get it programmatically....when app is running in user's environment. Besides, right-clicking gives the path in the host machine...whereas I need the path in Android phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My intention is to get the full path to this file

Resources are not files on the device. They are files on your development machine. They are entries in an APK file on the device.

> Is there a way to get the absolute file path to files in res or assets folder?

No, sorry.

> If its not possible in these two folders, how about external storage?

I would use internal storage, such as `getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()` on `Context`.

Comment: Thank you....But its weird that I have to use Java methods to read files, in a C++ app.

Comment: @NightFuryLxD: It's possible that the NDK has equivalents to those methods -- I have done very little NDK work. However, you do need *something* to tell you where the directories are, as the values vary based on OS version, which user is using the device, and device manufacturer adjustments. IOW, you cannot hard-code the directory name.